# Clone private repo with "Gitlab Workflow" vscode extension

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am using the [Gitlab Workflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fatihacet.gitlab-workflow) extension and I would like to clone a private Gitlab repository. I have created a GitLab Personal Access Token and I also gave it to the extension. But if I check the extension commands with:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>: `gitlab`

Then there is no `git clone` or a similar command to load a normal repo and certainly not a private repo.

Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

I used this article (translated it using Chrome's Right Click -> "Translate into English"): https://herwig.de/anleitungen/entwicklung/gitlab/workflow-vscode-git-gitlab.html#bestehendes-gitlab-repository-in-vs-code-kopieren

Then instead of "ctrl+shift+p: gitlab:.." I used "ctrl+shift+p: git: .." and there is the option "clone". You need to have Git installed though.

PS: You will be asked to enter your GitLab credentials. Be careful not to enter wrong credentials because git remembers them and updating the credentials took me half a day. If occasionally this happens, use Windows Credentials manager to update them.